# Can I use membase as database?

Tags: membase

I want to make some product to offer key-value data system. but local memory is limited.
so, I try to use membase as database. but membase is cache. i afraid whether the data stored in membase is go away or not. can i use membase as databse ? it is safe?

thank you.

Comment: Why not use something like SQLite?  If memory is an issue, you want to get as much of the data to a storage device as possible.

Comment: i want high speed. rdb like sqlit is slow than i expected.

Comment: Well, what do you want -- low memory consumption or high speed?

Comment: @cdhowie i want all of both. but memory consumption will be more bigger, i want to use clustering system. the system i will make must not slow any time.

Comment: If you want to use a cluster to improve performance, use PostgreSQL hot standby servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you use Membase buckets (in Membase there are memcached and Membase buckets) then everything will be persisted to disk. If the items on disk are greater than the number of item that can fit into memory then only the most recently used items will be held in memory.

Also, it is recommended that your working set fits into memory. If your working set is greater than can fit into memory then Membase will begin to take a performance hit.

Membase is also very safe. It runs in many mission-critical production systems. Zynga for example uses it to power Farmville.